How to show a dialog when using a spinbox in tkinter
I have a spinbox in my tkinter application and I want to show a warning in certain circumstances
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

widgets = None
root = None

def main() -> None:
    global widgets
    global root

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Spinbox')
    root.geometry('400x400')
    widgets = tk.IntVar()

    spin_box = ttk.Spinbox(
        root,
        from_=1,
        to=40,
        textvariable=widgets,
        command=_widgets_change,
    )
    spin_box.grid(row=0, column=0)

    root.mainloop()


def _widgets_change() -> None:
    if widgets.get() > 2:
        root.update_idletasks()
        result = messagebox.showwarning(
            '',
            'Too big',
            parent=root
        )
        print(result)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This works if I increase the value in the entry, but if I use the up-down button I get into a loop with the error

_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "grab" command: application has been destroyed

How can I get around this?
(Linux - Manjaro)

Try commenting out the root.update_idletasks() part.

Makes no difference - have you tried it?

No error here, python 3.8 windows

No, can't reproduce your issue, just a suspicion. Another try would be to set the state of spinbox to disabled before creating the messagebox. The error should only occur if the instance of Tk is destroyed and the underlying tcl interpreter is still alive. Can you post the full error stack?

PS: of course you need a mechanic to reinstate the spinbox with root.after(200, ...) to check properly. Since grab is designed to grab the events outside the window tree a design fault where the ButtonRelease event is needed could potential lead to this.

Thank you - disabling removes the error, but after spin_box.config(state=""), the value just keeps increasing. Any ideas? I've tried widgets.set(3). Is this an issue with the Linux implementation?

I'm unsure about the origin of this error, would need to check the source. You might open up a ticket. In the meantime you might get around it by using widgets.trace_add instead of the command option.

Why do you set the range to 1 to 40 and disallow values ​​greater than 2? This is confusing. Can you dynamically configure the spinbox range depending on the circumstances?

That error would happen if things were shut down with a grab present (from within an event handler). The code as written in the question shouldn't produce that error; something critical has been omitted (such as destroying the widgets in the _widgets_change function).

@8349697 Because values greater than 2 are allowed - The question states I want to warn the user

@DonalFellows The code, as written, does produce the error on my system - Linux, Manjaro

When does it produce it? In response to what user action?

" but if I use the up-down button "
